# Polyline not behaving correctly in IE9

Tags: google-maps

I'm using a simple javascript to overlay Lat & Long lines on a map. It works fine on my old machine (IE8, Windows XP) but on my new machine (IE9 on Win 7 64bit) polylines are drawn with incorrect line width and transparency.  The script is identical in both cases.
The polyline is defined like this:

```
var gridLines = new google.maps.Polyline({
path: gridCoords,
strokeColor: "#FF0000",
strokeOpacity: 1,
strokeWeight: 1
});
```

In IE8 the grid is correctly drawn (i.e, fully opaque and 1 pixel line width). In IE9 the grid is drawn as semi-transparent with a 2-pixel line width. All the lines are vertical or horizontal.

Does anyone have an idea why this is so?

NB I'm not including the rest of the script because I suspect there's a simple issue here.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have `gridLines` defined twice? Perhaps it is somewhere else with the 2px width and half opaque?

Comment: No, it's the only definition. I've stripped the script down to bare essentials just to check, and the same script behaves differently on the 2 machines.

Comment: I've also tried the script on my laptop (IE9 on Vista) and on the Windows 7 machine but using Firefox instead of IE - both displayed polylines incorrectly. Could this be a Win7/Vista issue, I wonder?

Comment: OK, I've worked on this and found that it's not just an issue with Polyline - it affects lines, polygons, triangles and rectangles that are horizontal or vertical lines of 1 pixel linewidth. They will always be drawn as 2 pixels linewidth at 50% opacity. Lines of more than 1 pixel width are correctly drawn.